# DropDownListFor is changing SelectedItem I've put on Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, html.dropdownlistfor

I am using cache on SelectListItems in my asp.net MVC app to store SelectListItems I'm using on lots of pages. The issue is that when I'm using it trough DropDownListFor, if I provide a selected value to this DropDownListFor, the SelectListItems looks to be changed... And I want to keep th SelectListItems in cache without "selected"  property!

Here is the cache:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAllPersonnelCached()
{
CacheHelper.SaveToCache("mykey", valueToCache, 240); //HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add
CacheHelper.GetFromCache<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>("mykey"); //HttpContext.Current.Cache["mykey"]
}
```

This is the properties of the model I'm using

```
        public int? personnelSelected{ get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> personnelList{ get; set; }
```

And How I fill it:

```
responsibleSelected = 100;
personnelList = GetAllPersonnelCached();
```

And here is how I am using the data on HTML part

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.personnelSelected, Model.personnelList, "PlaceHolder", new { data_placeholder = " " })
```

When I am running this code for a webpage, it works well. BUT then, when I call the GetAllPersonnelCached, it gives me all item as expected but the ListItem that has id 100 is "selecteditem". WHY? The fact that I'm using DropDownListFor makes changes on the List (referenced by the cache property in memory)? If yes, how to prevent this? Make the select list item readonly?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs#L370) of  the `DropDownListFor` shows that this extension method internally sets the `Selected` property.

Because a `SelectListItem` is a reference type, this change occurs on the corresponding item in the cache.

One way to prevent this is to return new `SelectListItem` objects from the `GetAllPersonnelCached` method, instead of the original cached ones.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAllPersonnelCached()
{
    CacheHelper.SaveToCache("mykey", valueToCache, 240); 
    var cachedItems = CacheHelper.GetFromCache<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>("mykey");

    return cachedItems.Select(o => new SelectListItem(o.Text, o.Value);
}
```

---

You might consider not to cache the `SelectListItem` instances, but the personnel-data objects instead which you transform to `SelectListItem` instances on retrieval.

```
// Assume your PersonnelData looks like below.    
class PersonnelData
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAllPersonnelCached()
{
    // valueToCache is a list of PersonnelData objects.
    CacheHelper.SaveToCache("mykey", valueToCache, 240);
    var cachedPersonnelData = CacheHelper.GetFromCache<IEnumerable<PersonnelData>>("mykey");

    return cachedPersonnelData.Select(o => new SelectListItem(o.Name, o.Id.ToString());
}
```

Comment: OK, I read that DropDownListFor didn't used the Selected property but in fact yes. I should have read the source code. Thank you, I will save the non-selectListItem object in cache!

Comment: *proud to give bounty to a belgian mate

Comment: ;) Glad I could help